# How to verify values in table row are not sorted using jasmine expect

Tags: jasmine, protractor

i was trying to test the table data is sorted or not , i am taking particular column data to test the data . but i am getting an error at the end of the test like "Expected false to be true."

like this i am trying

```
var perGain = [];
    var elm = element.all(by.repeater('stock in transactions').column('stock.gain'));
    elm.each((td) => {
        td.getText().then((val) => {
            perGain.push(val);
        })
            }).then(() => {
                expect(perGain.every((val, i) => (i < perGain.length - 1 ? val <= perGain[i + 1] : true)) === true).toBe(true);
            });
```

this is an array i am getting in perGain

[ '-42,314.40',
  '-34.45',
  '-29,666.52',
  '-30.47',
  '-22,283.50',
  '-36.61',
  '-22,267.92',
  '-33.41',
  '-20,097.32',
  '-31.53',
  '-18,403.00',
  '-51.73',
  '-18,354.86',
  '-20.68',
  '-18,331.67',
  '-46.54',
  '-17,842.30']

need to test the table data is sorted or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to loop through the td array and make individual expect. You manually sort the given array and check if the sorted array is not equal to the original array. Look at the below example.

```
var tdValues = element.all(by.repeater('stock in transactions').column('stock.gain')).getText();
var tdValuesSorted = tdValues.then(function(values){ 
          return values.sort() 
});
expect(tdValues).not.toEqual(tdValuesSorted)
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks that you are trying to sort strings not Numbers.

You should change (eg. while pushing) values from cells to numbers.

Yo can also check this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-sorted

EDIT:
You should also remember to remove `,` from your data.